# WebClient.DownloadStringAsync throwing Security Exception in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, webclient

First time using Silverlight ever! Following an online tutorial. I'm creating an app which allows the user to search for stories from the Digg website using a WebClient and displays them in a data grid in a Silverlight control.

Here's the code:

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string topic = txtTopic.Text;

    string diggUrl = String.Format("http://services.digg.com/stories/topic/{0}?count=20&appkey=http%3A%2F%2Fscottgu.com", topic);

    WebClient diggService = new WebClient();
    diggService.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(diggService_DownloadStringCompleted);
    diggService.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(diggUrl));
}

void diggService_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null)
    {
        DisplayStories(e.Result);
    }
}
```

Whenever I put a break point on the `diggService_DownloadStringCompleted` event handler and click the search button `e.Error` always equals a System.Security.SecurityException with no message and an inner exception of the same type with a message of 'Security error.'. The stack trace is:

at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)

at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result)

at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)

After some heavy googling I've seen people mention a crossdomain.xml file. Not entirely sure what this is but I added one to root directory of the web server running the Silverlight control any and added the following text. didn't make any difference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

What's going on?

Comment: Did you resolve this? I am having the same problem

Answer (score 2):

The crossdomain.xml file needs to be placed on the server you're trying to download the file from, not on the server that serves the Silverlight application.

If the server doesn't have a crossdomain.xml file, the Silverlight runtime does not allow your  application to download data from that server. By default, it can only access the server it was downloaded from (same origin policy).

Comment: ok well considering this tutorial is on the digg website i'm pretty certain they'd have a crossdomain.xml on their server. is there anyway of finding out?

Comment: http://services.digg.com/crossdomain.xml doesn't look like a well-formed crossdomain.xml file.

Comment: It's not a crossdomain.xml file. Apparently, when using services.digg.com, it's interpreting the request as a RESTful method and fails with a confusing error.

Answer (score 0):

Digg.com doesn't have a crossdomain file (meaning that Silverlight and Flash clients cannot directly use the API). Direct access from Silverlight is not possible.

One work around would be to make a proxy on your web host. The proxy will call Digg's API's from your web server rather than directly from the Silverlight client.

Silverlight ==> YourWebHost ==> Digg.com

Another workaround would be to use their JavaScript API instead, and then use the JavaScript bridge to communicate to JavaScript from Silverlight.

Silverlight ==> JavaScript ==> Digg.Com ==> JavaScript ==> Silverlight

For a JavaScript call:
http://developers.digg.com/response

Silverlight bridge reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645076(VS.95).aspx
Walkthroughs:
Silverlight to JavaScript:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221359(v=VS.95).aspx
JavaScript to Silverlight:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221414(v=VS.95).aspx

Comment: Digg has a crossdomain file http://services.digg.com/crossdomain.xml so any ideas why this wouldn't work?

Comment: aren't all those security restrictions a bit far fetched when you can bypass them by using the Javascript bridge?

Comment: @GeorgeBirbilis- I said that in my answer.