# System Security Exception in Silverlight app making GET request

Tags: silverlight, securityexception

I am new to silverlight. I have been trying to patch up a silverlight app that makes a get request to some site over the net, say google. However, I keep getting the system.security exception again nd again. I read various other posts and what i gathered is that for these things to work u need to choose HOST APPLICATION IN A NEW WEBSITE option while creation of the project, i have done that, but still get the same exception. I downloaded the app from http://www.shinedraw.com/data-handling/flash-vs-silverlight-simple-http-post-request/ and ran it by clicking **debug** in VS2010, still it gave the same exception. 
Please tell me what i am doing wrong, i know its cross domain issues, but dont know what else to do. 
The second answer at this post - [WebClient.DownloadStringAsync throwing Security Exception in Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265681/webclient-downloadstringasync-throwing-security-exception-in-silverlight), I think, offers a workaround, but does this means there is no way to access such services from silverlight directly?? -

Experienced users please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call a web service other than from your own domain directly from a Silverlight application. If you want to to this, you would have to install a cross-domain policy on the server that hosts the service. But you can always install a web service within your own web application (that hosts the Sivlerlight app) and call the other service from that service. It's one sercie call more but it works also with services you don't own.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your reply. Solved the problem, I was just sort of confused abt how silverlight is meant to be used. Re-read the microsoft documentation and it seems pretty obvious now, abt why such cross domain architecture has been introduced. Ur reply helped a lot. Thnx